# Replace a variable as string with results from a subroutine in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to replace the variable "ex" with it's string value(which it gets from subroutine "potatoex()" and put it in the definition of another variable "goodge",
not getting any syntax error but this seems to be not working out.
Please help.

```
sub potatoex {    
  my $potato="Junos: 17.4DCB";
  if($potato = ~/"Junos: 17.4[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*"/) {
    print "/var/home/smoketest/dhcpv6.pl.28709.log";
  }
}
```

main :

```
{
  my $ex= potatoex();
  my $goodge= "Apurva $ex Arnav";
  print $goodge;
}
```

CURRENT O/P : /var/home/smoketest/dhcpv6.pl.28709.logApurva 1 Arnav

EXPECTED O/P: Apurva /var/home/smoketest/dhcpv6.pl.28709.log Arnav

Thanks,
Apurva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `print`ing from your subroutine instead of `return`ing the value from it.  Try using `return` in `potatoex`.

```
sub potatoex {    
  my $potato    = q{Junos: 17.4DCB};
  my $returnVal = '';

  if( $potato =~ /Junos: 17\.4[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*/ ) {
    $returnVal = q{/var/home/smoketest/dhcpv6.pl.28709.log};
  }

  $returnVal;
}

{
  my $ex     = potatoex();
  my $goodge = qq{Apurva $ex Arnav};

  print $goodge;
}
```

While you could use `return` in an `if` block above (instead of `print`), I instead decided to use a variable, which will always return either the value you are trying to or an empty string.  You could explicitly state the return `return returnVal;`, but it isn't required as perl allows implicit returns (make note of this and figure out if it should fit in your best practices or not).

Comment: Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at jdoodle.pl line 7, near ""/var/home/smoketest/dhcpv6.pl.28709.log";"
Execution of jdoodle.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: That's because I typed the code without testing it and had syntax errors ;)  The variables were missing `$` symbols.  Should be fixed now

Comment: I tried this : sub potatoex {    
  my $potato="Junos: 17.4DCB";
  if($potato = ~/"Junos: 17.4[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*"/) {
    return "/var/home/smoketest/dhcpv6.pl.28709.log";
  }
}
main :

{
  my $ex= potatoex();
  my $goodge= "Apurva $ex Arnav";
  print $goodge;
}

Comment: @ApurvaArnav yw, just remember to upvote, select answers, and contribute on SO ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is the first time I am using SO, how to upvote and select answers?

Comment: @ApurvaArnav the number next to the answer/question can be upped or downed by a voter and there is a checkmark under that.  Selecting answers to your questions will help you gain more points.  More points will enable more features for you on the site.

Comment: I have selected the answer, but whenever I change the number from 0 to 1, it gets changed back to 0

Comment: @ApurvaArnav it's no worries to me, I have enough pts, just good that you know how as you begin to use the site and even help others

Comment: I have one question, if you could help. How to match exact pattern in perl?

Comment: Suppose I want to choose from "Junos: 17.4-xyz" and "Junos: 16.1-abc" , If it is 17.4, I want associated if clause to be executed , otherwise 16.1 if clause. How to do that?

Comment: @ApurvaArnav I would first have to get you going through the process.  First have you searched the site and/or google?  If they wouldn't reveal anything, I would suggest asking a new question.  This is the added benefit of more points for you and more points for others.  It also permits multiple answers, since your question can be solved in multiple ways.